# Oracle 11g error in creating a function

Tags: function, oracle11g

I'm new to 11g and stackoverflow,
I need to create a function to calculate the age of any employee, can someone help me?

Oracle is telling me

**My error: Error at line 6: PL/SQL: Statement ignored**

**My code:**

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION age (datee in varchar2)
return number
as
total number(2);
Begin
total:=( (SYSDATE - TO_DATE (datee) ) /365, 0 );
return total;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The calculation looks wrong, try this line instead:

```
total:=(SYSDATE - TO_DATE (datee) ) /365;
```

or if this was a truncation attempt

```
total:=ROUND( (SYSDATE - TO_DATE (datee) ) /365, 0 );
```

The error message you mentioned is only one, the actual problem description was shown before. You might need to use a beter IDE to see all errors (transated sample):

```
Error(6,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(6,8): PLS-00382: This expression has the wrong type
```

Comment: the same answer below, i can create but now idk how to use
I do a call age('03-03-1995')

Answer (score 0):

This line is problem:

```
total:=( (SYSDATE - TO_DATE (datee) ) /365, 0 );
```

what you want to do? 
Result of two dates in oracle ( like in your example) is decimal number which express time span in days.
By dividing by 365 I'm expecting that you want to return this time span in years.
But what is this:

```
( span , 0 )?
```

If you wan to round this value you can use:
FLOOR - to round fown, CEIL to round up, or ROUND to round to nearest:

```
total:=FLOOR((SYSDATE - TO_DATE (datee) ) /365);
```

Also you can use TRUNC to remove decimal places.

Comment: Hello, now i can create my function but, when i call the function gives me that error ORA-00911: invalid character, My goal is to create a function that gives the age when i put the (mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: You have to add mask to TO_DATE function that parses data correctly. In your case TO_DATE(datee,'MM/DD/YYYY'), you can read more about here: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php